# how use if clause code within html in asp.net razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, if-statement, razor, web-applications

I want to write "if clause" in razor for example

```
 @if (ViewBag.name == null)
   {
   <h3> name is empty.... </h3>
  @}  else {ViewBag.name }
```

but I get error!
would you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@** is used to start writing razor statements i.e. C# code and within html we can still use razor statements starting with **@**

The following is the correct syntax for it:

```
@if (ViewBag.name == null)
{
   <h3> name is empty.... </h3>
}
else 
{
    <h3>@ViewBag.name</h3>
}
```

it can be more simplified like below:

```
 <h3> @(ViewBag.name == null ? "name is empty...." : ViewBag.name) </h3>
```